# loop over columns with different names

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to run a loop in which I perform a merge.
In each stage of the merge I create variables with new suffixes. After the first stage I have VARIABLE_1 and VARIABLE_2. After the second merge VARIABLE_1, VARIABLE_2 and VARIABLE_3. etc
Now I need to rename and perform operations on the last two in each stage.
So after the first merge I need to rename VARIABLE_1 and VARIABLE_2
On the second stage I need to rename VARIABLE_2 and VARIABLE_3  etc

What seemed logical to me is to run the merge as follows:

```
 for count in range(1,200):
        df=pd.merge(df, dforig, left_on=['ID'], right_on=['ID'], suffixes=('count', 'count+1'),copy=True, how='left') 
        df=df.rename(columns={'VARIABLE_count':'VARIABLE_count-2', 'VARIABLE_count+1':'VARIABLE'})
```

Before the first merge df = dforig
After the first merge df is the new dataset
dforig is still the original dataset.

So after the first merge state I have now:

```
  ID      VARIABLE_1         VARIABLE_2 
  x         y                  z
```

and this should become:

```
  ID      VARIABLE_-1         VARIABLE 
  x         y                  z
```

This is df

dforig still looks like:

```
ID   VARIABLE
```

Problem is: 'VARIABLE_count' is not a valid reference to a column. 
Is there a proper way to call columns where the name changes dependent on the iteration of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can  use parameter `on` in [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html), then remove `'` from variables `count` and before concanecate cast `int` to `str`:

```
for count in range(1,200):
    df=pd.merge(df, dforig, on='ID', suffixes=(count, count+1), copy=True, how='left') 
    df=df.rename(columns={'VARIABLE'+str(count):'VARIABLE' + str(count-2),
                          'VARIABLE'+str(count+1):'VARIABLE'})
```